# a particular linear combination

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Fix $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in\mathbb{N}$. I'd like to know if one can characterize the natural numbers that belong to the set $$\{b_1a_1+\ldots+b_na_n:\,b_j\in\{-1,0,1\}\}.$$

EDIT: Maybe this question doesn't have a solution. In fact, I was interested on solving the following problem: consider natural numbers $a_1<a_2<\ldots<a_7< 100$. Suppose that, if $b_1a_1+\ldots+b_na_n=0$ with each $b_j\in\{-1,0,1\}$, then $b_j=0$ for all $j$ (we have some sort of linear independence). Then every $a\in\{a_7+1,\ldots,100\}$ can be written as $a=c_1a_1+\ldots+c_na_n$, where each $c_j\in\{-1,0,1\}$.

Comment: probably not, but you can calculate them in time $|S|n$, where $S$ is the set you want. Does tha help?

Comment: Thank you for you comment. But I'm interested on the exact description of that set. For example, if $a_j=2^{j-1}$, I could prove that the set is $\{-2^n+1,\ldots,2^n-1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that there is a characterization, because if there is, we should be able to efficiently test if an element $m$ is in this set; this is equivalent to the problem P: test if there are two subsets of $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$ whose sum differs by $m$.

This problem is NP-hard with a reduction from the Partition problem known to be hard: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem.

The reduction is simple: given a set $V$, we want to know if there exist two sets with the same sum. Solve $P$ on the set $V \cup \{m\}$.